# When I fetch(url).then(console.log), the console.log does not execute

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, mern

Hi I've been in a limbo with the problem. I'm trying to use the update method to update the iterations of clicks in my URL shortener project. The iterations update in the DB but then it isn't reflecting on the front end. I was thinking it would update in the then() function after fetching but then it seems like it didn't go in the then() function. My question is that is there something wrong with the code or is there an alternative way for it to get to the then()?

Client side (React)

```
const id = record._id;
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/update/${id}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateData),
    })
      .then((res) => { <-- Not executing :(
        console.log("Update");
        // function to refresh the page
        handleRefresh(); 
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Server side (Mongoose)

```
urlControllerRouter.post("/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  UrlModel.findById(id)
    .then((updateURL) => {
      updateURL.click = req.body.click;
      updateURL
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(`[UPDATE] ${updateURL}`);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`[UPDATE] ${err}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`[UPDATE] ${err}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: is your catch console.log working?

Comment: sadly no the console.log() isnt executing

Comment: did you try without serializing  body: JSON.stringify(updateData),?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server isnt making a response after getting the request from the client so the connection is pretty much in limbo for lack of a better word.
You need to send a response to client

```
urlControllerRouter.post("/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;

  UrlModel.findById(id)
    .then((updateURL) => {
      updateURL.click = req.body.click;
      updateURL
        .save()
        .then(() => {
         
          console.log(`[UPDATE] ${updateURL}`);
          res.status(200).json({
           message: updateURL
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(`[UPDATE] ${err}`);
         res.status(500).json({
              message: err.message
          })
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`[UPDATE] ${err}`);
          res.status(200).json({
               message: err.message
            })
    });
});
```

Btw, with fetch you need to add two thens to get the data you want.
But in your case you don't want to get the data so one would do
So something like this

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3001/update/${id}`, {
     method: "POST",
     headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
     body: JSON.stringify(updateData),
   })
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then((res) => { <-- Not executing :(
       console.log("Update");

       // function to refresh the page
       handleRefresh(); 
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
     });
```

Also you should actually add the backend link as a proxy value to your package.json as a better way of making the API call to the backend.

```
"name": "",
  "version": "",
  "main": "",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001", //note the proxy
  "license": "",
....
```

Then you just need to do this with fetch

```
fetch(`/update/${id}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateData),
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solution worked for me. I'll up vote it once I can, again thank you so much.